# Is it possible to obtain the PGP message given only the public key and the signature?

Tags: security, openssl, cryptography, gnupg

Given a 2048bits SHA256 PGP public key and the PGP signature of a unknown text, how hard it would be for a dedicated operation (Eg.: a cryptocurrency mining farm) to obtain the the text?

Example:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
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=Dvhl
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

And the signature:

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----

iQFIBAEBCAAyFiEEIdo0SYj3hyuLILYIpWnL4hoXOrcFAmFUY5cUHGphdm9udGUy
MDUyQHZvbi5uZXQACgkQpWnL4hoXOrch5wf/WlVrtizRMlhKjQiCSU6rLVeT+CaV
NQ5xDc1xESeS0ax5+GYi+96o4UGIjRSTmMNSAo6IrbWzpgbG5Moa6XvjyHL0ri7S
rIYN3CJMV4mkb6ow9Zg5rvfizsOifdkBOBZv26EehZobu71UD9kAPSh+yLqwrutN
ew79b4O8p3D8MuTcHZ4J3Cb/N/bAU4eV7zp54O7YL7Zdpbg4LbmgWYg7uIcsYPl3
tiPS1b8dl65/gMzcAKO8Nw+lg8ODRdHLJlHUR2SxWaHLpC4Vzgp2rnBQMQ0TVxfV
Y2KYMDWhbdu9CQ/Aljxc2MdZl0sZTMypsTmY+WGSak6mlI+roO8E8NWqWQ==
=YKLY
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

I imagine that increasing the bit size of the key or increasing the size and complexity of the unknown text are ways to increase the difficulty. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the PGP key is an RSA key you can get the hash of the message that has been signed with (an RSA signature is an encrypted message hash that can be decrypted by the user's public key). Now you have the hash, but a hash function is a one-way function which means you can not reverse it.

For small messages (a few bytes) you may be able to brute force the message by generating the hash message for every possible message (a bit similar like attacking password by brute force testing).

Alternatively in case you would have a large set of plain text messages and you only want to identify the message the hash of the signature belongs to, this could be done too (this is similar to using an password list and testing each password on the list if it has the matching hash).

For other signature schemes like ECDSA as far as I know even retrieving the message hash is not possible, you can only test if a given message hash "matches" the present signature.

Comment: The key is an RSA key, the hashing algorithm used was sha256, and the hash recovered from the signature is (in hex) `21e784fa8a447f9a4a573b24d569cea5ac94a049dd9b230e862f32df538b6279`.

Comment: Interesting. But now with the SHA256 hash in hands won't it be just like mining cryptocurrency? As far as I know, Bitcoin farms are huge SHA256 cracking machines, which attempts to uncover the input of a given SHA256 hash by brute force. If this is correct then increasing the "randomness" and size of the input will increase the difficulty in cracking it. Right?

Now regarding what you said about ECDSA this is even more interesting, I'll look into that. Thank you.

@President James K. Polk: This was nice, thank you.

Comment: It has very little in common with mining cryptocurrency.

Comment: @fschuindt Cryptomining typically has an adjustable "difficulty," which means that only a part of the hash need match a specified value. The difficulty increases exponentially with the length of the match. Further, miners are only testing one field in the whole message; the message format is not open-ended. That would be a much more difficult problem.

Comment: @erickson Splendid. Thanks a lot, I think I have everything settled like: It's possible in theory, but beyond our current computational power to do so.

Comment: @fschuindt Yes, although it’s not just impossible for our current technology, it’s impossible (barring any flaw in the algorithm) for any tech in the future becoming practical, based on lower limits in the energy cost of computation.